# column.footerCell is undefined on Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

When adding a footer for a mat-table on Angular Material, I'm getting this error:

> column.footerCell is undefined

Below is my code:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="people" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <strong>{{ element.name }}</strong>
        </td>
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{ people.length }} people</td>
    </ng-container>

    ...

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Data looks like this:

```
public displayedColumns = ['name'];
public people = [
  {id: 1, name: 'John'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jane'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Joe'},
];
```

If I remove the footer codes, everything works well. 
Any ideas on this?

Comment: Not enough code. I cant see anywhere `column.footerCell` . can you provide a demo on stackblitz.com .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe in angular 6 and 7, <td mat-footer-cell> is a column.footerCell. There might be something I'm missing based on your comment.

Comment: ok, can you show the data you are passing to the table component ?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post to show the data.

Comment: There must be something else which causes the problem that we don't see here. Can you post the complete template and component? Because if I use what you posted here, it works fine, check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-gxfzy4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 8):

You must be missing this code part in your other ng-containers

```
<ng-container>
...
<td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
</ng-container>
```

Even if you don't like any data or information in some footer columns, you have to include this directive